# MySQL Workbench 6.0 - incorrect syntax template

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, workbench

I am new using MySQL Workbench, I am actually discovering it now.

I can't find a clear tutorial or documentation where they explain why it is this syntax.

I have a table, called chefs, with id, name and country columns. I want to populate this table, using MySQL Workbench, following the tutorial, I end up doing right click on the table I want to insert, then click "send to SQL editor", and then click on "Insert statement". When I do this, a template appears on my Query screen like this:

```
INSERT INTO `cooking_book_new`.`chefs`
(`id`,
`name`,
`country`)
VALUES
(<{id: }>,
<{name: }>,
<{country: }>);
```

[image]

I have checked and verified, that if I use the regular syntax I use to use for mysql it inserts the row:

```
INSERT INTO chefs (id, name, country) VALUES (1, 'chef1', 'Country1');
```

But, as the whole point of trying to use this software is to make everything easier, I would like to know why it prepares that query, and how should I introduce the data there.

I have tried this:

```
INSERT INTO `cooking_book_new`.`chefs`
(`id`,
`name`,
`country`)
VALUES
(<{1}>,
<{'chef1'}>,
<{'country1'}>);
```

And also this:

```
INSERT INTO `cooking_book_new`.`chefs`
(`id`,
`name`,
`country`)
VALUES
(<{id:1 }>,
<{name:'chef1' }>,
<{country:'country1' }>);
```

But everything seems wrong. Does anyone know how to use this syntax? I know I could just do the query as I have tested that works like:

```
   INSERT INTO chefs (id, name, country) VALUES (1, 'chef1', 'Country1');
```

But it would be better if I understand how MySQL workbench works.

Thank you!

Comment: Those are only representational values. TBH, I only used Workbench once and didn't really like it, since I like to hardcode everything. The `<{}>` are probably propriety to the program. There must be some documentation in help files for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual for Workbench probably contains an explanation for it, but given that it is so large, it would (probably) take (me) much longer to keep searching, as I did and finding something on their website with similar syntax.

As per the manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-generating-sql.html

The `<{}>` are only representational (expressions) values.

For example:

Update Statement

```
UPDATE `sakila`.`actor`
SET
`first_name` = <{first_name}>
WHERE <{where_expression}>;
```

Let's look at the manual on INSERT:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

You're not going to use `{VALUES | VALUE}` or the rest of those `[...]` right? Those are "options".

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)]
    [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE}
```

It is up to you to replace those "representational" values with the proper syntax, that needs to be used in conjunction with the reference manual.

Comment: sorry Fred -ii- , I am really slow understanding things :/
So, when I click into the table and "insert statement" and appears this: 
INSERT INTO `cooking_book_new`.`chefs`
(`id`,
`name`,
`country`)
VALUES
(<{id: }>,
<{name: }>,
<{country: }>); 

I have to do what? I understood you are saying the <{ }> are only representational so shouldn't it work like this?

INSERT INTO `cooking_book_new`.`chefs`
(`id`,
`name`,
`country`)
VALUES
(1,
'chef1',
'france'); 

If I should understand it by now... don't worry, I have left on the side this software for now...

Thank you!

Comment: @eve_mf I understand and you'll get the hang of it. Software can be a bit hard to get a handle of at first; I've been down that same road a few times and they don't make it easy sometimes, given it's such an elaborate piece of software. What you wrote in your question `INSERT INTO chefs (id, name, country) VALUES (1, 'chef1', 'Country1');` is the basic syntax. Ticks `\`` are mostly used around tables/columns if a reserved word is used, or contains a space and/or a hyphen. (and you're welcome). If something doesn't work, check for errors as there could be constraints or something else.